# Troubleshooting MVC4 Web API Performance Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, memorycache

I have an asp.net mvc4 web api interface that gets about 54k requests a day.

http://myserv.x.com/api/123/getstuff?whatstuff=thisstuff

I have 3 web servers behind a load balancer that are setup to handle the http requests.

On average response times are ~300ms. However, lately something has gone awry (or maybe it has always been there) as there is sporadic behavior of response times coming back in 10-20sec.  This would be for the same request hitting the same server directly instead of through the load balancer.

```
GIVEN:
- System has been passed down to me so there may be gaps with IIS confiuration, etc,.
- Database: SQL Server 2008R2
- Web Servers: Windows Server 2008R2 Enterprise SP1
- IIS 7.5
- Using MemoryCache aggressively with Model and Business Objects with eviction set to 2hrs
- Looked at the logs but really don't see anything significantly relevant
- One application pool...no other LOB applications running on this server
```

Assumptions & Ask:
Somehow I'm thinking that something is recycling the application pool or IIS worker threads are shutting down and restarting thus causing each new request to warmup and recache itself.  It's so sporadic that it's tough to trouble shoot right now.  The same request to the same server comes back fast as expected (back to back N requests) since it was cached in about 300ms....but wait about 5-10-20min and that same request to the same server takes 16seconds.

I have limited tracing to go by as these are prod systems so I can only expose so much logging details. Any help and information attacking this or similar behavior somebody else has run into is appreciated.  Thx

**UPDATE:**
The w3wpe.exe process grows to ~3G. Somehow it gets wiped out and the PID changes so itself or something is killing it every 3-4min I see tons of warnings in my webserver (IIS) log:

> A process serving application pool 'MyApplication' suffered a fatal
>   communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The
>   process id was '1732'. The data field contains the error number.

Comment: Hows your cache hit behaving. How frequently it refreshes itself ?

Comment: @TabishSarwar: hi, somewhat of a newbie on cache hitting but the evictionpolicy is set to expire every 2 hrs.

Comment: I would suggest you to enable tracing on Production Server (or wherever you can replicate/simulate large calls). See whats the frequency of calls getting delayed .. If you observe. You might come up with some pattern to look into. Otherwise I understand your problem .. its very open ended. it could be anything at this point.

Comment: Sometimes it could be your Network issue, not Application Issue. You get what i am trying to say here.

Comment: @TabishSarwar: sure at this point it could be a lot of things for initial investigation. what could the possible things be for hardware?  do you think it could have something to do with worker IIS threads spinninp up the shutting down or IIS config issues...application pool cycling?

Comment: If your application was working fine . You made sure there were no application changes deployed. All of a sudden it started to happen . I will try to observe what is exactly going on. See logs /calling patterns .. if they seem fine. I will there could be network issue. re-routing issue causing delays on switches/ routers ... could be IIS ..could be cache not behaving as expected.. could be indexing issue in database .. could be server memory spiking up . I will make a checklist and start ruling them out one by one at this point.

Comment: just made an update to the case desc.

Comment: I am not sure if you have resolved your issue by now. Can you check one more thing in application pool advanced settings that Enable 32 bit application  to true.

Comment: @TabishSarwar: Hi, yes, tried checking that and was causing my requests to fail.

Comment: So was that settings was disabled you are saying and its now resolved coz of that now?

Comment: @TabishSarwar: it was set to false...when I enabled it I was receiving 500's for all of my http requests. Set back to false but still get same behavior (w3wp.exe crashes). I have attached diag debug and have a stack trace to work with...system.objectdisposedexception.  More than likely issues with the threading model for receiving requests and caching issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 4-5 days of assessing IIS and configuration vs internal code issues I finally found the issue with little to no help with windbg or debugdiag IIS tools.  Those tools contain so much information even with mini dumps or log trace stacks that they can be red herrings. Best bet was to reproduce it by setting up a "copy intelligently" instance of a production system, which we did not have at the time and took a bit for ops to set something up.

Needless to say the problem had to do with over cacheing business objects.  There was one race condition where updates on a certain table were updating an attribute to that corresponding business object (updates were coming from multiple servers) which was causing an OOC stackoverflow that pretty much caused the cacheing to recursively cache itself to death thus causing the w3wp.exe process to die and psuedo-recycle itself.  It was one of those edge cases that was incredibly hard to test and repro in a non-production environment.